# Backups of home dirs in the face of snap (best practices)

Tags: filesystem, backup, snap

To backup all user data, it made sense for me to backup /home/*user*. I could opt-out by configuring different paths outside /home for big data like the bitcoin blockchain, Spotify cache or Steam library (the latter is thankfully still possible since Steam is a .deb).

Snaps only have access to the home dir (and /media?), so anything used by snap needs to be in /home. Is there a recommended way to deal with the backup aspect in particular in Ubuntu, or is it too different between users? I use zfs replication, and maybe I could create separate datasets for bitcoin, etc, under /home/*user*, to exclude them. Right now, /home is the dataset, so I can't even check if this works.

Comment: I do not think you will get a clear answer to this only peoples opinions.

Comment: Yes, it may not be a good question for this site. Opinions or ideas is all I was hoping for, but maybe this doesn't fit the format. Feel free to downvote, I guess, and we'll see what comes.

Comment: Seems like "snap" is less important to this question about backups than "huge dataset".

Comment: @user535733 Sure isn't just snap. But snap is catching on a bit, and it's removing the option to configure the data storage location. Software that had this option before -- Bitcoin and Spotify included -- now can't.

Comment: I should add.. a snap-based option to map paths outside of home would be one of the best possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using bind-mounts as the primary way to force the storage locations (quite a hacky way, but I didn't get any replies). For instance, to redirect two directories under /home into /data/ephemeral, I did this in a script file:

```
    sudo mount --bind /data/ephemeral/daedalus-mainnet/chain /home/fa2k/.local/share/Daedalus/mainnet/chain;
    sudo mount --bind /data/ephemeral/daedalus-mainnet/Logs /home/fa2k/.local/share/Daedalus/mainnet/Logs;
```

It's also possible to put things in `/etc/fstab`.

```
/var/local/daedalus             /home/fa2k/.daedalus    none    bind
```

The examples are not for a Snap but for a Nix application Daedalus, but the theory is the same.